# Creating a for loop to check list values in Python

Tags: python

I'm having issues with a homework assignment. I need to create a for loop that counts how many times a value appears in a list. Here is the code:

```
def get_test_scores():
    tests = []
    for i in range(SIZE):
        test_score = int(input("Enter test score #"+str(i+1)+" in the range 0-100: "))
        while (test_score <0) or (test_score >100):
            print("ERROR!")
            test_score = int(input("Enter test score #"+str(i+1)+" in the range 0-100: "))        
    tests.append(test_score)    
    return tests

def find_perfect(tests):
    count = 0
    for test_score in tests:
        if test_score == 100:
            count += 1
    return count
```

I can't get the count value to reflect how many 100's I input

Comment: Did you mean to indent `tests.append(test_score)` one more level?

Comment: Please provide the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  Your posted code defines two functions and ends without calling either of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're working on things like this (be it assignments or production code), it's best to test *each individual function* to make sure that they're working properly. For example, try running `find_perfect` with different (hard-coded) lists; you'll find it gets the right answer each time. Now try testing `get_test_scores` and print out the output. Oops!

Your problem is that you're only appending the very last test score. The line `tests.append(test_score)` should be inside the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

your `tests.append(test_score)` will happen once because its out side of the for loop, try this :

```
def get_test_scores():
    tests = []
    for i in range(SIZE):
        test_score = int(input("Enter test score #"+str(i+1)+" in the range 0-100: "))
        while (test_score <0) or (test_score >100):
            print("ERROR!")
            test_score = int(input("Enter test score #"+str(i+1)+" in the range 0-100: "))        
        tests.append(test_score)    
    return tests
```

By the way i think its worth to count on the fly how many 100 you have and not iterate again, in python you can return few value from a function like a tuple ,
for example :

```
def get_test_scores():
    tests = []
    count = 0
    for i in range(SIZE):
        test_score = int(input("Enter test score #"+str(i+1)+" in the range 0-100: "))
        while (test_score <0) or (test_score >100):
            print("ERROR!")
            test_score = int(input("Enter test score #"+str(i+1)+" in the range 0-100: "))
        if test_score == 100:
            count += 1
        tests.append(test_score)    
    return count, tests
```

usage :

```
count, scores = get_test_scores()
```

count is a number, scores is a list of scores

Answer (score 0):

make `tests.append(test_score)` inside for loop by adding tab before it